What do these numbers have in common?

121242
132284
2344816
52432416
3158232

Hint(s):

 This has nothing to do with letters or sequences.
 The numbers are two (technically more) numbers concatenated.
 Treating each digit as singular objects is not the way I would go about doing this.
 Think of a starting point for each number(a seed if you will) and go from there.


They are all even, divisible by 2...

(though that is correct, understood by you;) it is not the answer, unfortunatly for u (this is a joke.)

Any other hints? I am working on it

Is this a good track? rot13(nyy ahzore raqf jvgu (2^3eq qvtvg), sbe rknzcyr ynfg ahzore'f 3eq qvtvg vf 5, naq guvf ahzore raqf jvgu 32)

@M.Riyan this should be more clear now.

@franckvivien that is in the right direction.


 I've found three clues... and their ways of numbers construction are basically the same, $2^1 = 2$, $2^2 = 4$, $2^3 = 8$, $2^4 = 16$, $2^5 = 32$  (But I'm not sure if there are any other possible patterns...
 



Although this is in the right direction, the question is asking about how to create the whole number. In an algorithmic way if one must say, I'll add a hint to make it clearer.

What do you mean create the whole number? The question asks for anything common among the numbers.

The common pattern among these is the way that they are created.

@AlphaNoodle
this anwwer clearly shows that rot13(tvira 3 qvtvg n,o,p, gur erfhyg vf gur pbanpgnargnvba n.o.p.2^n.2^o.2^p)

@franckvivien although yes, but I would want any people stumbling to this question to understand the answer by just reading it rather than having to figure out the concatanation of the first 3 digits to the results. (Given that that person wants the answer to be fully explanatory.) But I'll accept it anyway because the comments and the clues make it obvious I believe.

I couldn't understand what these tables are supposed to show and how they are related to the question.  Only with franck vivien's comment did I figure what it tries to say.  You should make clear the tables are to be superposed.

Exactly what I meant^.
